# NXT Mindstorms software glitch

Tags: nxt, programming, software

My FLL team was doing some practice programming exercises this morning.  One group wrote a program using color sensors, no issue.  The next group opened a new program window and attempted to open a color sensor block, but were unable to do so.

All of the other sensor blocks opened correctly, but the color sensor would not open the formatting section, allowing for specifying what the sensor is supposed to do.

We tried everything!

And then, when the first group went back to their program to make refinements, the color sensor formatting areas had gone blank and could no longer be used.

The software broke while we were using it.  Any guidance anyone would be helpful.  Thanks!